# tear off the trees’ bark

Tags: vocabulary

> The water gives the trees their wide shape. Large trees can store as
>   much as 140,000 liters. Thirsty elephants **tear off** the trees’ bark and
>   wood to get to the water inside.

Is the definition #3 and #1 in the links below correct?

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tear1_1?q=tear

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tear+off

Comment: Why would you think that it is not correct? What else might it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is an appropriate definition of "tear off":  "Remove by tearing."